# Storing data and later recalling it -simple way

Tags: macros, undefined

I need to place the text repeatedly so I want to store it and reuse it. However, I could not define the macro for it. Any guidance please.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pifont }
\begin{document}

\storedata \mydata{\ding{172} \ding{173} \ding{174} \ding{175} \ding{176} \ding{177} \ding{178} \ding{179} \ding{180} \ding{181}}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular} {p{.08\textwidth}p{.5\textwidth}p{.25\textwidth}}  \multicolumn{3}{l}{Policy Dimension D1: Raw materials} \\ \hline
Code & Element & Rating (Severity 0 to 10) \\ \hline
D1E1 & This is a string of text for the statement & \getdata \mydata  \\
D1E2 & This is a string of text for the statement & \getdata \mydata  \\
D1E3 & This is a string of text for the statement & \getdata \mydata  \\
D1E4 & This is a string of text for the statement & \getdata \mydata  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You can just do `\newcommand{\mydata}{\ding{172}...}` and the use `\mydata` in the `tabular`. Or do you want to have programmatic macros `\storedata`/`\getdata`? They would be anyway some wrapper around `\newcommand`.

Comment: @campa, thanks! It works well.

Comment: Also take a look at `\sbox` / `\savebox` and `\usebox`.

Comment: Do you want just to repeat the same list of tokens or do you want to process it in different ways?

Comment: Hello @egreg I just wanted to repeat the same list but I just wanted to make it cleaner. So the trick with the `\newcommand` worked!